# Blocking a website using Java

Tags: java, http, httprequest

I am trying to block certain websites using a web application. So, when a I type a url suppose "http://www.google.com" it should first check whether google is blocked by my application or not. If not open the website otherwise reject the browser request to open it. I am unable to find a way to capture all HTTP request from browser so that I can process it.

I Know proxies are the most suitable option but is there any alternative solution to this. After some searching I found a library - jpcap (a network packet capture library) and I was wondering if this could help me or not?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to create is a proxy-server.

You have to configure the browser to go through the proxy, then you can deny websites, reroute them etc.

There are many proxies already there (open source and commercial) that offer what you want.

For example: Squid http://www.squid-cache.org/

See Wikipedia description of a proxy here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Many firewall products offer the service of a transparent proxy, redirecting all http/https traffic going through the firewall into a proxy server. It seems, you have a direct connection but your packages are really filtered. Aka transparent proxy.

If your assignment does not allow this context, you need to check the assignment again, if you really got the scope of filtering right.

You cannot take over the browser's ip communication from a servlet or servlet filter. Using a (servlet) filter, you can only filter requests directed to your application. One step above, using an application server valve (Tomcat uses this term, others may use a different one), you can only filter requests directed at that server. One step above (or below) your application server is the physical server and the network it is running in.

If your client does not share the same network as your server, you can't even apply transparent proxy to it. Since browsers are running on the client computer, most clients in the world do not share the same network zone as the server.

It just does not work as you expect it.

Comment: That idea crossed my mind. But the thing is, this a school assignment and using proxies or configuring browser is off-limits

Comment: I understand you and couldn't agree more on than this. But whole point of me asking this question was to know a alternate way.